# Get only specific attributes with from Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel

I've been reviewing the documentation and API for Laravel Collections, but don't seem to find what I am looking for:

I would like to retrieve an array with model data from a collection, but only get specified attributes.

I.e. something like `Users::toArray('id','name','email')`, where the collection in fact holds all attributes for the users, because they are used elsewhere, but in this specific place I need an array with userdata, and only the specified attributes.

There does not seem to be a helper for this in Laravel? - How can I do this the easiest way?

Comment: Other viewers might be interested in `Collection::implode()`. It can take a property and extract it from all the objects in the collection. This doesn't answer this question exactly, but it might be useful for others who have come here from Google, as I did. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-implode

Comment: If you're looking to do the inverse and get all properties except certain properties, use [except](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-except)

```Users::get()->except(['password', 'secret_answer']);```

Answer (score 271, accepted):

You can do this using a combination of existing `Collection` methods. It may be a little hard to follow at first, but it should be easy enough to break down.

```
// get your main collection with all the attributes...
$users = Users::get();

// build your second collection with a subset of attributes. this new
// collection will be a collection of plain arrays, not Users models.
$subset = $users->map(function ($user) {
    return collect($user->toArray())
        ->only(['id', 'name', 'email'])
        ->all();
});
```

**Explanation**

First, the `map()` method basically just iterates through the `Collection`, and passes each item in the `Collection` to the passed in callback. The value returned from each call of the callback builds the new `Collection` generated by the `map()` method.

`collect($user->toArray())` is just building a new, temporary `Collection` out of the `Users` attributes.

`->only(['id', 'name', 'email'])` reduces the temporary `Collection` down to only those attributes specified.

`->all()` turns the temporary `Collection` back into a plain array.

Put it all together and you get "For each user in the users collection, return an array of just the id, name, and email attributes."

---

### Laravel 5.5 update

Laravel 5.5 added an `only` method on the Model, which basically does the same thing as the `collect($user->toArray())->only([...])->all()`, so this can be slightly simplified in 5.5+ to:

```
// get your main collection with all the attributes...
$users = Users::get();

// build your second collection with a subset of attributes. this new
// collection will be a collection of plain arrays, not Users models.
$subset = $users->map(function ($user) {
    return $user->only(['id', 'name', 'email']);
});
```

If you combine this with the ["higher order messaging" for collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#higher-order-messages) introduced in Laravel 5.4, it can be simplified even further:

```
// get your main collection with all the attributes...
$users = Users::get();

// build your second collection with a subset of attributes. this new
// collection will be a collection of plain arrays, not Users models.
$subset = $users->map->only(['id', 'name', 'email']);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've marked this as the accepted answer, because it works like a charm with existing Laravel functionality. - Now, this could be made available to the collection via a custom collection class, like I described in my alternative solution.

Comment: That's it. But I wish there were a less verbose way to emulate QueryBuilder's `::get([ 'fields', 'array' ])` behaviour. Basically, it would be handy for "dumps".

Comment: for arrays you can do `$newArray = Arr::only($initialArray, [  'id', 'name' /* allowed keys list */ ]);`

Comment: this is great but i wonder how it can work if i have a nested array inside

Comment: In recent versions of Laravel this can be written even more concise: `$users->map->only(['column', ...])`

Comment: @Fx32 Thanks for the comment. I have added this information to the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't `return $user->only(['id', 'name', 'email']);` be `return collect($user)->only(['id', 'name', 'email']);`? Tested on Laravel 6.13.1 and what you suggested fails with `Call to undefined method stdClass::only()`..

Comment: @RomeoSierra No. In all the code in the answer, `$user` is an Eloquent model, which has an `only()` method. Whatever code you wrote to test, you were attempting to call `only()` on a plain PHP `stdClass` object, which won't work.

Comment: Ahh yeap. That's the case. I am working on a `DB::`. The result is an Eloquent collection of standard php objects. :) Sorry about the false alarm...

Answer (score 26):

use `User::get(['id', 'name', 'email'])`, it will return you a collection with the specified columns and if you want to make it an array, just use `toArray()` after the `get()` method like so:

`User::get(['id', 'name', 'email'])->toArray()`

Most of the times, you won't need to convert the collection to an array because collections are actually arrays on steroids and you have easy-to-use methods to manipulate the collection.

Comment: The collection is already created by a previous query, where more attributes are needed. Therefore I need to generate a data array where I only have specific attributes.

Comment: You can either make your query dynamic with passing an array of columns to return or you can do another `->get(['id', 'email', 'name'])` which won't requery the database but it will return a new collection with only the selected values. Methods like pluck / lists, get, first, etc. have the same names in both, the query builder class and the collection class.

Comment: Ruffles, that does not work in Laravel 5.3. - The query builder "get" method does in fact take columns, but it also performs another query. The collection's "get" method can extract a specific model by key from the collection, which is not what I am after here.

Comment: get() always returns a collection, it doesn't matter if it's DB::table()->get() or Model::get(), so if you save the query in a variable and run the get method on that $query variable, you shouldn't get another query to the database.

Comment: When I store the query in a variable like $query = Model::where(...), then it runs a query to the database whenever I do a $query->get(). - Also, your suggestion imho is not a desired solution for the problem. I've solved it with som new array functions that I implemented via a custom collection (se my own answer).

Answer (score 12):

Method below also works.

```
$users = User::all()->map(function ($user) {
  return collect($user)->only(['id', 'name', 'email']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 10.45.1 or above you can do `$collection->select('id', 'name', 'email')` or `$collection->select(['id', 'name', 'email'])`.

https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_select

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blame/e550f2bf06e4d2f44bf241d2861eea059904976f/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php#L927

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to define `$hidden` and `$visible` attributes. They'll be set global (that means always return all attributes from `$visible` array).
2. Using method `makeVisible($attribute)` and `makeHidden($attribute)` you can dynamically change hidden and visible attributes. More: [Eloquent: Serialization -> Temporarily Modifying Property Visibility](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

Comment: I do not want this to be global, but select the attributes to extract from the collection dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I have now come up with an own solution to this:

**1. Created a general function to extract specific attributes from arrays**

The function below extract only specific attributes from an associative array, or an array of associative arrays (the last is what you get when doing $collection->toArray() in Laravel).

It can be used like this:

```
$data = array_extract( $collection->toArray(), ['id','url'] );
```

I am using the following functions:

```
function array_is_assoc( $array )
{
        return is_array( $array ) && array_diff_key( $array, array_keys(array_keys($array)) );
}



function array_extract( $array, $attributes )
{
    $data = [];

    if ( array_is_assoc( $array ) )
    {
        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute )
        {
            $data[ $attribute ] = $array[ $attribute ];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ( $array as $key => $values )
        {
            $data[ $key ] = [];

            foreach ( $attributes as $attribute )
            {
                $data[ $key ][ $attribute ] = $values[ $attribute ];
            }
        }   
    }

    return $data;   
}
```

*This solution does not focus on performance implications on looping through the collections in large datasets.*

**2. Implement the above via a custom collection i Laravel**

Since I would like to be able to simply do `$collection->extract('id','url');` on any collection object, I have implemented a custom collection class.

First I created a general Model, which extends the Eloquent model, but uses a different collection class. All you models need to extend this custom model, and not the Eloquent Model then.

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as EloquentModel;
use Lib\Collection;
class Model extends EloquentModel
{
    public function newCollection(array $models = [])
    {
        return new Collection( $models );
    }    
}
?>
```

Secondly I created the following custom collection class:

```
<?php
namespace Lib;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection as EloquentCollection;
class Collection extends EloquentCollection
{
    public function extract()
    {
        $attributes = func_get_args();
        return array_extract( $this->toArray(), $attributes );
    }
}   
?>
```

Lastly, all models should then extend your custom model instead, like such:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
class Article extends Model
{
...
```

Now the functions from no. 1 above are neatly used by the collection to make the `$collection->extract()` method available.

Comment: Check out the Laravel documentation on extending collections: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#extending-collections

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I needed to select values from a large array, but I wanted the resulting collection to only contain values of a single value.

`pluck()` could be used for this purpose (if only 1 key item is required)

you could also use `reduce()`. Something like this with reduce:

```
$result = $items->reduce(function($carry, $item) {
    return $carry->push($item->getCode());
}, collect());
```

Comment: Whadyaknow - it actually works. I've never used a collection as the $carry in a reduce before. 

However! This will return a flat array of values (no keys - much like pluck()) but the OP wanted to retain the keys along with the values.

Answer (score 1):

This is a follow up on the @patricus [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38429046/4311336) above:

Use the following to return collection of object instead of array so you can use same as models object i.e. `$subset[0]->name`

```
$subset = $users->map(function ($user) {
    return (object) $user->only(['id', 'name', 'email']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a follow up on the patricus [answer][1] above but for *nested* arrays:

```
$topLevelFields =  ['id','status'];
$userFields = ['first_name','last_name','email','phone_number','op_city_id'];

return $onlineShoppers->map(function ($user) { 
    return collect($user)->only($topLevelFields)
                             ->merge(collect($user['user'])->only($userFields))->all();  
    })->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

This avoid to load unised attributes, directly from db:

```
DB::table('roles')->pluck('title', 'name');
```

References: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results (search for pluck)

Maybe next you can apply `toArray()` if you need such format

Answer (score 0):

### Context

For instance, let's say you want to show a form for creating a new user in a system where the User has one Role and that Role can be used for many Users.

The User model would look like this

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{   
    /**
     * User attributes.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'role_id'
    ];


    /**
     * Role of the user
     *
     * @return \App\Role
     */
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
...
```

and the Role model

```
class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * Role attributes.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description'
    ];
    
    /**
     * Users of the role
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

---

### How to get only the specific attributes?

In that specific form we want to create, you'll need data from Role but you don't really need a description.

```
/**
 * Create user
 *
 * @param  \App\Role  $model
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function create(Role $role)
{
    return view('users.create', ['roles' => $role->get(['id', 'name'])]);
}
```

Notice that we're using `$role->get(['id', 'name'])` to specify we don't want the description.

Answer (score -2):

this seems to work, but not sure if it's optimized for performance or not.

`$request->user()->get(['id'])->groupBy('id')->keys()->all();`

output:

```
array:2 [
  0 => 4
  1 => 1
]
```

Answer (score -4):

```
$users = Users::get();

$subset = $users->map(function ($user) {
    return array_only(user, ['id', 'name', 'email']);
});
```