# Get only specific attributes with from Laravel Collection and relation

Tags: php, laravel

I want to remove some attributes from the final result and found this here
[Get only specific attributes with from Laravel Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412091/get-only-specific-attributes-with-from-laravel-collection)

This works for the top level but what is need is to remove some attributes from a related item
say user has one access_card and access_card have some long text details as one of its attribute.

i want to remove that attribute from final result. Is is possible with the method mentioned in link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a "code" field on access card, you can try something like that:

```
$users = Users::with('access_card')->get();
$subset = $users->map(function ($user) {
    return collect(
        [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'access_card' => $user->access_card->code,
        ]);
});

dd($subset);
```

Comment: bit tedious but works, i was hoping something like just naming the attribute as like the only function's parameter array.

Answer (score 0):

```
User::with(['access_card' => function($query){
    $query->select('code');
} ])->select('id', 'email')->get();
```

Assumig you want user id and email with an access card and only the card_code

Comment: thanks for tip, i will try this in somewhere else.

i forgot to mention that i only want to modify the collection, this is for a clean api response json, the collection is already used by a view