# Laravel 6.x working with Eloquent and arrays - avoid queries inside foreach

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

Hi I have a lot of Eloquent queries in foreach loops all over my app and I am trying to avoid this practice where possible.

Example:

```
$statuses = Statuses::get(); // or Statuses::all(); // What's the difference because I use them mixed?

$statusList = [];

foreach ($statuses as $status) {
    $statusList[$status->id] = $status->status_title;
} // How do I just get my array of the id => status_title in single Eloquent query?

// Return $statusList to use in my select drop-down...
```

I have many more areas where I am using foreach to get what I want and in some of these I am querying maybe 10 to 100s of times - here is what I now tried based off of a different Stack Overflow answer:

```
$statuses = $statuses->map->only(['id', 'status_title']);
```

But this does not give me the format of array I need, I need one dimensional [id] => [title] but that one is giving me the column names with it.  source: [Get only specific attributes with from Laravel Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412091/get-only-specific-attributes-with-from-laravel-collection)

Thanks

Thank you! Trying this out gives me exactly the primary key as array key and statuses title as value without column names. Sorry I just realised this example does not have query in foreach.

I have one more question that I don't know how to do: Now I want to concatenate some columns like:

```
$statusList = Status::pluck('status_title', 'status_outcome', 'id')); 
$array = $statusList->all();
what I'm trying to do is [id] => [status_title . ' ' . status_outcome]
```

so basically I have my array keys as the primary key ID and the value as concatenated title and outcome?

Please help I am having problems with the ->pluck() method:

```
Statuses::select("CONCAT('status_title', ' - ', 'status_outcome') AS status, id")->pluck('status', 'id')->all();
```

trying to get array but pluck() is behaving differently in different queries of mine and sometimes I get an error. I'm also trying to pluck more than 2 columns it gives an error e.g.

```
Statuses::pluck('status_title', 'status_outcome', 'id')->all() I also tried ->get() and ->toArray()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `pluck` method is for:

```
$statusList = Status::pluck('status_title', 'id');
```

This would get you a **Collection** keyed by 'id' with 'status_title' as the values. If you want to convert that **Collection** to an **array** call `all()` on the **Collection**:

```
$array = $statusList->all();
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Queries - Retrieving Results - Retrieving A List Of Column Values](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#retrieving-results) `pluck`

Also what you have isn't any querying in a loop. You are querying once and just iterating the result in your example.

---

If you need to use some functions (not all supported DBs have `concat`):

```
$list = Status::selectRaw("concat(status_title, ' - ', status_outcome) as con, id")
    ->pluck('con', 'id');
```

Comment: in one line should be:  $statuses = Statuses::all()->pluck('status_title', 'id');

Comment: @koalaok ... not really, that would pull all the records, hydrate those models with all the attributes to then iterate through them to just get those 2 fields ... this would only select the needed fields and not hydrate any models, very different things happening, this is calling `pluck` on the Builder, not the Collection

Comment: I think he wants all records... maybe he can select just the wanted columns though. But I'm not sure it will be a performance improvement.

Comment: nope, that isn't what their code says but perhaps they need more data, would have to see

Comment: Thank you! Trying this out gives me exactly the primary key as array key and statuses title as value without column names.  Sorry I just realised this example does not have query in foreach.  I have one more question that I don't know how to do:

Now I want to concatenate some columns like: `$statusList = Status::pluck('status_title', 'status_outcome', 'id')); $statusList->all()` . what I'm trying to do is [id] => [status_title . ' ' . status_outcome] so basically I have my array keys as the primary key ID and the value as concatenated title and outcome?

Comment: $comp= Statuses::select("CONCAT('status_title','status_outcome') AS name, id")->get()

Comment: @koalaok they just changed their question, please feel free to add an asnwer

Comment: Please help I am having problems with the ->pluck() method:

`Statuses::select("CONCAT('status_title', ' - ', 'status_outcome') AS status, id")->pluck('status', 'id')->all();` trying to get array but pluck() is behaving differently in different queries of mine and sometimes I get an error.

I'm also trying to pluck more than 2 columns it gives an error e.g. `Statuses::pluck('status_title', 'status_outcome', 'id')->all()` I also tried `->get()` and `->toArray()`

Comment: you can't pluck more than 2 columns, it  creates a list, key => value, so only 2 columns ... i will add an update for you

Answer (score 0):

Using mysql concat() and pluck() Laravel Helper would do the trick you want:

```
$statuses = Statuses::select("CONCAT('status_title', ' ', 'status_outcome') AS status, id")->get()->pluck('status', 'id');
```

Comment: Hi this gets the concatenated string as value now with key as the id.  Just sanity check here, is this output as an array? yes?

Comment: Please help I am having problems with the ->pluck() method: `Statuses::select("CONCAT('status_title', ' - ', 'status_outcome') AS status, id")->pluck('status', 'id')->all();` trying to get array but pluck() is behaving differently in different queries of mine and sometimes I get an error. I'm also trying to pluck more than 2 columns it gives an error e.g. `Statuses::pluck('status_title', 'status_outcome', 'id')->all() I also tried ->get() and ->toArray()`