# Getting specific attribute value from Eloquent\Collection in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get the attribute "date" value from the following returned data, how I can get it?

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#267 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Crisis_indicators_data {#255 ▼
      #table: "crisis_indicators_data"
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:4 [▼
        "c_i_data_id" => 1
        "date" => "2022-05-23"
        "indicator_id" => 30
        "value" => 11
      ]
      #original: array:4 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the following ways, but no data returned

```
$row_data_temp->date
$row_data_temp[0]->date
$row_data_temp[0]['date']
```

I don't want to use for loop or foreach because performance-wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// get your main collection with all the attributes like this...

```
$users = Users::get();
```

// build your second collection with a subset of attributes. this new
// collection will be a collection of plain arrays, not Users models.

```
$subset = $users->map(function ($user) {
    return $user->only(['id', 'name', 'email']);
});
```

stackoverflow ref:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412091/get-only-specific-attributes-with-from-laravel-collection)

Comment: asslam o alikum.brother tell me if your problem still not solve.

Comment: You can also do it like this : `$subset = $users->map->only(['id', 'name', 'email']);`

Comment: Thanks it seems that map solve the problem, but I need also to print only name for example, I mean that subset contains name,id, email. and I need name

Comment: ok .that is too shorter

Comment: @mohammedS.yaghi not sure to understand your issue, take a look at the [pluck function](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck)

Comment: $subset = $users->map->only(['name']);

Comment: and then dd($subset); to print it

Comment: are you get solution?

Comment: I tried pluck, it works perfect, but it return the value between [], I can do some logic do remove it, but I wonder if there is function to return the value without []

Comment: value() insted of pluck try this one

Comment: I used some thing like this echo $subset->pluck('date'); how I will apply value() in mentioned code echo $subset->pluck('date');

Comment: echo $subset->value('date');

Comment: unfortunately the code echo $subset->value('date') didn't work :)

Comment: Any way your solution solve my problem, but I have to make some extra logic to remove  [], thanks mate for your efforts :)

Comment: ok .jzakAllah. thanks a lot to vote me

Comment: You deserve to vote your answer, Thanks a lot